# HTTP server error handler in Typescript and Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm transforming Typescript for my backend codebase, but when listening to http server `Error Event`, I'm facing an issue about `[ts] property syscall does not exist on error`. I think the Error type is wrong here, but apparently Node.js does not provide the default error type for this callback function. Anyone can help me with the correct Error type?

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
})

server.listen(3000);
server.on('error', onError);

function onError(error: Error) {
  // [ts] property syscall does not exist on error
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Trying changing the type of your `error` variable from `Error` to `NodeJS.ErrnoException`.  This type is an interface that extends the base `Error` interface and adds the `syscall` property, among others.

Source: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/index.d.ts#L401

```
export interface ErrnoException extends Error {
    errno?: number;
    code?: string;
    path?: string;
    syscall?: string;
    stack?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're using types, like `@types/node`, the class you want to use is `NodeJS.ErrnoException`. Saying use `any` to solve the problem of lacking a type, is the same as saying if you want to stop punctures on a car, take off the wheels.

Answer (score 1):

This is because not every Error object needs to have a syscall property.

You may be able to fix it changing this:

```
function onError(error: Error) {
  // [ts] property syscall does not exist on error
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

to this:

```
function onError(error: any) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

See this issue comments for some background:

- https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/666

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I want to say. I though @types/node has already got build-in type for this callback. But I still want to use static checking instead of using any

Comment: Absolute wrong thing to do, you're just dropping the use of types.